# Reading Test resources from jar file in java

Tags: maven, junit

I have one project A which has some test resources. 
POM file Of Project B has dependency of Project A.

How Can I use test resources from Project A in test cases of Project B.

Comment: Why do you need the test resources in another project? Are we talking about unit tests or integration tests? Of do you need a separate resources package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Maven you have to depend on some artifact. Unless tests are packaged into a jar file you can't depend on them. So you either need to move the resources into production code or you need to [create jar with tests](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then you can depend on it:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <version>version</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```